# Spinner loading on routechangestart with Authentication library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, hottowel

I'm using the Hot Towel angular library (https://github.com/johnpapa/hottowel-angular-bower) on a project I inherited from a senior developer.

I'm also incorporating Auth0's authentication library for Angular.

I need to restrict some routes to authenticated users. To do that, I set some route properties.
`isLogin: true` for routes which is restricted to non-authenticated users.
`requiresLogin: true` for routes needing authentication, and the opposite for those who don't. In order to check these properties on each runthrough, I use `$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart' function())`.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, auth, common, config) {
    var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn,
        log      = getLogFn('auth handle'),
        events   = config.events;

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, nextRoute, currentRoute) {
        if (nextRoute.$$route && nextRoute.$$route.settings && nextRoute.$$route.settings.requiresLogin) {
            if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
                $location.path('/login');
                log('User not authenticated');
            }
        }
        if (nextRoute.$$route && nextRoute.$$route.settings && nextRoute.$$route.settings.isLogin) {
            if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
                $location.path('/');
                log('User is authenticated');
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Now, it seems this is interfering with the spinner functionality included with Hot-Towel. In Shell.js I find the following:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',
    function (event, next, current) { toggleSpinner(true); }
);

$rootScope.$on(events.controllerActivateSuccess,
    function (data) { toggleSpinner(false); }
);

$rootScope.$on(events.spinnerToggle,
    function (data) { toggleSpinner(data.show); }
);
```

What happens is that the spinner never stops spinning (e.g. vm.isBusy = true because a controller is never activated and resetting this), how would I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is that you could use an event ($broadcast) to notify when the un authorized access is made so it is then received by the controller that turns off the spinner.

Comment: Doing this `$rootScope.$broadcast(events.controllerActivateSuccess, true);` in an app.run method, but the spinner keeps on rolling. Updated OP with the method in it's entirety.

Thanks for replying, though.

Comment: That's too early. You need to do it after the async task you are calling is completed. If that is an auth task (sounds like it) then call the event after it is done to turn off the spinner.

Comment: Alright, I see! Well, I solved it for the moment with a $timeout and utilising the activateController method from common, but I didn't really like my solution. I noticed the auth library I'm using fires an event when the login is successful, so I could then fire the controllerActivateSuccess when that happens and I would be golden.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't studied your code for very long but shouldn't you use `$routeChangeSuccess` to stop the spinner?

```
$scope.isViewLoading = false;
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
    $scope.isViewLoading = true;
});
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    $scope.isViewLoading = false;
});
```

Comment: The spinner is included from a third-party library, which I explained in my initial question.